# Java heap dump error with jmap command : Premature EOF

Tags: java, heap-memory, eof, heap-dump

I have encountered below exception during execution of below command

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap_dump.bin <process_id>
```

output:

```
Dumping heap to <file_name>
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
            at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.readInt(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:248)
            at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.execute(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:199)
            at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.executeCommand(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:217)
            at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.dumpHeap(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:180)
            at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.dump(JMap.java:242)
            at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:140)
```

JDK version : *1.7.0_45*

VM_OPTs :

```
-Xms2g -Xmx4g  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=2 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
```

*Hardware : RHEL 5.x, 4 core CPU Linux machine 6 GB RAM*

As per oracle bug report database ( http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6882554), this issue has been fixed state but I am still getting jdk 1.7 version with build no:45

*Can you suggest any solution other than upgrading to Jdk 1.8, which is not possible in my case due to other dependencies?*

***EDIT:***

I have tried with below command and this command too does not work (**generated partial dump file**) and shows same Premature EOF.

```
jmap -J-d64 -dump:format=b,file=<filename> <pid>
```

I have triggered the command with the user, who started the process. That user had write permissions to the directory. The file was generated but it was incomplete.

*9 MB* file was written for *2 GB* heap, which is not usable for analysis.

Comment: Two things: What directory are you running the jmap in and as what user?

Comment: I triggered the command with the user, who started the process. That user had write permissions to the directory. The file was generated but it was incomplete. 9 MB file was written for 2 GB heap.

Comment: Possible explanations include filesystem quotas, a full filesystem or a `ulimit`.  Also, the bug you found is for MVM (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mvm-141094.html) not Java in general.  You aren't using MVM.

Comment: Looks like JVM has crashed during heap dumping. Is there `hs_err_pid.log` crash log? Try also forced mode (`jmap -F`).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34363274/646634) suggests using `live` in your `-dump`: `jmap -J-d64 -dump:live,format=b,file=<filename> <pid>`. This is most likely due to `-XX:+UseGCG1` for garbage collection. Can you give that a try and see if it works?

Comment: Are you facing same issue, when you invoke the heap dump from visual-vm?

Comment: I can't use it in production. The same command I have quoted in question is working fine in other environments properly and giving issue only in production.

Comment: I suspect the socket created in Linux is having problems, its not getting any input from target linuxvirtualmachine.
<code>
 try {
199            completionStatus = readInt(sis);
200        } catch (IOException x) {
</code>

Comment: may be your other environments are not on linux, this looks like a bug in Java. Also you can connect visual-vm remotely to your production system.

Comment: And one more small query : does live option causes Garbage collection before collecting dump?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brian's comment is helpful to resolve the issue.

If you are using `G1GC` algorithm in 64 bit machine:

*Below command does not work ( excluding `live` option)*

```
jmap -J-d64 -dump:format=b,file=<heap_dump_filename> <pid>
```

*you have to use below option to get the heap dump*

```
jmap -J-d64 -dump:live,format=b,file=<heap_dump_filename> <PID>
```

There are some suggestions to use `-F` option to force heap dump but as per oracle [technotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html):

> -F
>   Force. Use with jmap -dump or jmap -histo option if the pid does not respond. The live suboption is not supported in this mode.

Since heap dump is required with G1GC option, above option can't be used.